# Ember.js What should be made a Component?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, web-component, ember-components

Basically, if you were given a design of a web page with all kinds of UI patterns/elements, some with interaction and some just static, how would you decide what should be made into a component and what can just stay as html?

This is more of a philosophical question and goes beyond Ember.js; I included it because thats what I'm learning/using right now.

There are some patterns which should obviously be implemented as components, such as tab switchers or filters and my naive reasoning is that they have interaction and are used multiple times on the page. But how far do I go with that? Are each of these reasons sufficient to justify a component or are they only necessary or are they neither? Should a make a button component just because there are many buttons on the page? Should I make a slider component even if I know there will only ever be one slider on the page?

What are good rules of thumb to decide whether to implement something as a component? I could envision creating components for every single thing so that the entire page is just components within components. Surely that is too far? Especially given that Ember's components each have an instantiation cost and lifecycle, theres also a performance aspect to consider when deciding what should be a component right?

I'm interested to hear everybody's viewpoints. Thanks.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: @Kitler On the contrary, there are solid criteria for the decision to componentize which are worthy of discussion.

Comment: @torazaburo which is out of scope for stack overflow, it screams of opinion based and invites everyone to give their viewpoint, it is a good question but there is a close vote option specifically for such questions making it off topic.

Comment: Im glad that at least people think this question is worth asking. How can I reword this question? Or what is a more appropriate place to ask this question?

Comment: @aeyang either IRC or the ember community [slack](https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/) are suitable places for this discussion, you should also take the time and familiarise yourself with what you can and can't ask on [so] http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

I use components to keep everything organized. In theory you can make everything a component but you shouldn't exaggerate the use of components.

As a main rule, I use:
When a part of your website needs alot of code, you should put that code in a separate component.